# Qt/C++ Get list of QBluetoothLocalDevice

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

On my device I have multiple bluetooth adapter attached. In my case I want to get some info about the devices connected to the second adapter (calling pairingStatus() specifically). For this I need to get an instance of QBluetoothLocalDevice which provides this information. The issue is that I can not construct an instance when knowing the address of the adapter:

```
QBluetoothLocalDevice BluetoothConnector::getBluetoothAdapter()
{
    QList<QBluetoothHostInfo> adapters = QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices();
    QBluetoothLocalDevice device = QBluetoothLocalDevice(QBluetoothAddress());
    if(adapters.size() >= 2)
    {
        device = QBluetoothLocalDevice(adapters.at(1).address());
    }
    return device;
}
```

This is caused because the constructor is declared explicit. How can I construct or obtain a QBluetoothLocalDevice that is the second adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the problem is a bit unclear (e.g. which constructor is declared `explicit`?) but the code shown won't compile as it attempts to assign a [`QBluetoothLocalDevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothlocaldevice.html) which inherits from `QObject` and is, thus, not assignable/copyable.

Instead you should probably return a smart pointer to a newly created `QBluetoothLocalDevice` and let the caller decide what to do with it...

```
std::unique_ptr<QBluetoothLocalDevice> BluetoothConnector::getBluetoothAdapter ()
{
    auto adapters = QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices();
    if (adapters.size() >= 2)
        return std::make_unique<QBluetoothLocalDevice>(adapters.at(1).address());

    /*
     * No adaptor found so throw an exception.  You may want to return
     * a default constructed std::unique_ptr instead.
     */
    throw std::out_of_range("no adaptor found");
}
```

---

As an aside, your implementation of `BluetoothConnector::getBluetoothAdapter` doesn't appear to modify any member variables and should, therefore, be `const` qualified.